# How to deploy portus docker registry in linux server

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have tried deploying portus docker registry via dockerhub image and other options from gitbub but, none of them working for me.
I was able to create portus containers but when i launch the application it showed me error " something wrong in our lighthouse" and i was unable to debug this issue.